# NSArray returning null iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I have a method in which I save a userdefault in viewWillAppear like so:

```
self.getUserName = [defineXMLData objectForKey:@"fromUserName"];
                    NSLog(@"Saved Array %@" ,self.getUserName);

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [prefs setObject:self.getUserName forKey:@"voucherFromUserName"];
                [prefs synchronize];
```

I do get data from the array in my NSLog but when I try load the user default into the array it returns null? I tried with another saved user default from another view controller and it works.

I try to load the nsarray in viewDidload like so:

```
self.voucherArray = [prefs arrayForKey:@"voucherFromUserName"];
```

Even if I try to use the original array in which I saved the data it still does not work:

```
self.voucherArray = self.getUserName;
```

Comment: I read bad or: voucherFromUserName is different from fromUserNameVoucher ..?, and should be objectForKey, and not arrayForKey

Comment: Have you allocate your array [[NSArray alloc] init]; before you try to load data to it.

Comment: Print self.getUserName to make sure there is something there + @"fromUserName" should be @"voucherFromUserName" when you load.

Comment: I had a typo mistake, when I copied and pasted into stackoverflow the keys are of the same name.

Comment: Where do you  check for the NSUserDefaults data? In another VC, or in the same file along the line?

Comment: My array is actually getting called before I save my data. I need to move the method out of viewWillAppear. I thought is loads before viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `viewWillAppear` is called after `viewDidLoad` so you are probably trying to get the data from the userDefault before it is saved in it

Comment: Yes. You are right. The nsarray is called before I am saving the data. How can i work around this?

Comment: from where did you get 'defineXMLData' ? ... why you are saving it in 'viewWillAppear' ?

Comment: I want to run my method before loading my nsarray.

Comment: sorry I didn't get that ... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am running a method that calls a webservice and I save the data I want in a userDefault and then load it into an array in ViewDidLoad...

Comment: Is it a must to load the data in viewDidLoad method? ... Can you please put all your controller code?

Comment: You can load the data in the init, since they don't require UI, it will run first. Or use delegate to trigger an action the exact moment the web service has obtained data.